# Generically overloading operator new while considering alignment requirements

Tags: c++, alignment, operator-overloading, new-operator, generic-programming

## Situation

I am writing a memory manager for dynamic memory (de)allocations. For a `class A` to use it when `operator new` (or `delete`) is called, it is sufficient for `class A` to inherit from a `class CustomAllocate`, which itself overloads `new` and `delete` in a way that uses the memory manager.

## Problem

However, apparently I completely missed out on alignment requirements. Unfortunately, `CustomAllocate::new` has no information about how a `class A` inheriting from it should be aligned as the only parameter is the size of the requested memory. I am searching for a way to include alignment information without having to overload `new` (and `delete`) in every `class A` to use the memory manager.

## Idea 1 (and why it does not work)

Templating `class CustomAllocate` with an integer value representing the alignment requirements and inheriting like so: `class A : public CustomAllocate< alignof(A) >`.

Impossible because `alignof(A)` cannot be known at the time it has to be passed as template parameter, even though the passed parameter should never change the alignment requirements of `class A`.

## Idea 2 (and why it does not work)

Having a pure virtual function `virtual int CustomAllocate::getAlignment() = 0` that is implemented in every `class A` by copy pasting something like `return alignof(A);`.

Impossible because `new` is static and thus can never access a virtual function.

---

Any working ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat to my surprise, the following seems to work:

```
template <typename T> class CustomAllocate
{
public:
    void* operator new (std::size_t count)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling new, aligment = " << alignof (T) << "\n";
        return aligned_alloc (alignof (T), count);
    }

    void operator delete (void *p)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling delete\n";
        free (p);
    }
};
```

Test program:

```
class A : public CustomAllocate <A>
{
public:
    A (int a, int b) : a (a), b (b) { }
    int a, b;
};

int main ()
{
    A *x = new A (1, 2);
    std::cout << x->a << ", " << x->b << "\n";
    delete x;
}
```

Output:

```
Calling new, aligment = 4
1, 2
Calling delete
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/854bS1byiCPuRAgh)

Comment: Well, the point of overloading the operators is that I do not have to make any changes to existing new/delete calls: I can switch between standard new/delete and my own memory management (which uses placement new internally) by changing the inheritance or the implementation of CustomAllocate. Your suggestion would force me to change a lot of existing calls or, alternatively, overload new delete in every class I want to use CustomAllocate, which is what I intend to circumvent.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: *"Somewhat to my surprise"*. With CRTP, `T` is incomplete during the definition of the class, but not inside the definition of the method.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you, your idea did it. I didn't know of CRTP ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern ) before, interesting how you suggested it without seeming to know it.