# How to benifit from CRTP in a real example?

Tags: c++, crtp

According to my understanding CRTP(Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) is used when a class is derived from a specialization of a templated-base class. So the base class can access the functionality of derived class then delegate to derived class after casting the Parameter to a derived class. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template< class T> 
class Shape2D{
    public:
        Shape2D(double, double);
        virtual ~Shape2D();

        void SetDims(double dim1, double dim2) {
            static_cast<T*>(this)->SetDims(dim1, dim2);
        }

        double GetDim1() const;
        double GetDim2() const;
        double GetSurface()const;
        double GetPerim()const;
};

template<class T>
Shape2D<T>::Shape2D(double dim1, double dim2) {
    static_cast<T*>(this)->SetDims(dim1, dim2);
}

template<class T>
Shape2D<T>::~Shape2D() {

}


template<class T>
double Shape2D<T>::GetSurface()const {
    return static_cast<const T*>(this)->GetSurface();
}

template<class T>
double Shape2D<T>::GetDim1()const {
    return static_cast<const T*>(this)->GetDim1();
}

template<class T>
double Shape2D<T>::GetDim2()const {
    return static_cast<const T*>(this)->GetDim2();
}

template<class T>
double Shape2D<T>::GetPerim()const {
    return static_cast<const T*>(this)->GetPerim();
}

class Rectangle : public Shape2D<class Rectangle> {
    public:
        Rectangle(double, double);

        void SetDims(double, double);

        double GetDim1() const;
        double GetDim2() const;
        double GetSurface()const;
        double GetPerim()const;

        private:
            double itsLength, itsWidth;
};

Rectangle::Rectangle(double len, double wid) :
    itsLength(len), itsWidth(wid), Shape2D<Rectangle>(len, wid) {

}

void Rectangle::SetDims(double len, double wid) {
    itsLength = len;
    itsWidth = wid;
}

double Rectangle::GetDim1()const{
    return itsLength;
}

double Rectangle::GetDim2()const {
    return itsWidth;
}

double Rectangle::GetSurface()const {
    return itsLength * itsWidth;
}

double Rectangle::GetPerim()const {
    return ((itsLength * 2) + (itsWidth * 2));
}

int main() {

    class Rectangle rct(7, 5);
    cout << rct.GetSurface() << endl;
    cout << rct.GetPerim() << endl;

    cout << endl;

    Shape2D<class Rectangle>* pSh2DRect = 
        new Shape2D<class Rectangle>(7, 5);
    cout << "Surface: " << pSh2DRect->GetSurface() << endl;
    cout << "Perimeter: " << pSh2DRect->GetPerim() << endl;

    delete pSh2DRect;


    cout << endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

- I can't see any benefit above because I can achieve it without CRTP.
- I want a helpful example to clear my doubts about Static Polymorphism.
- What if a *derived `class`* doesn't inherit from a specialization where this derived class is not the parameter of the template base class?? eg:

  ```
  class Parallelogram : public Shape2D<Rectangle>{
       public:
          //...
  };
  ```

As you can see `Parallelogram` normally inherit from `Shape2D<Parallelogram>` not `Rectangle`. Is it a Undefined Behavior?

Comment: I am not sure that CRTP is really used properly with your example. There are many things code could profit from it (especially with embedded development). Your question is _too broad_ to be concisely answered here at least.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Would you mind to elaborate a good example?

Comment: Is [that one](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl) good enough for you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Thank you I'll check it.

Comment: Short cut for the whole concept is here: http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/docs/STTCL-Concept.pdf

Comment: There's a simple example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53179371/5743288 (I used it without realising)

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) give several example, I like [the one for clone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Polymorphic_copy_construction).

Comment: You can look here too: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/16/what-the-crtp-brings-to-code/